# Getting views folder path

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am getting the views folder path with this: `app_path()."/Views"`

Is there any better or more solid way of getting the views folder path? I mean, just in case the view folder is moved to somewhere else and it still works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Yes I guess it's possible to make it more prone to change. Just get it from the config like so:

> `Config::get('view.paths');`

This is actually an array of paths (folders) for your views. To change it, just look at the `/app/config/view.php` config file. It should be quite self-explanatory from there.

If you can access `$this->app` somehow (e.g. in a ServiceProvider), you also can obtain the configured paths by doing:

> `$this->app['config']['view.paths']`